# Chaining functions with callbacks while keeping separation of concerns

Tags: node.js, callback

In the codebase I picked up, we have a chain of async methods that expands to two modules with different functional purposes.

**i.e** we do some stuff with `GeneralTravel` and then pass on the data to `Hotel` related stuff:

```
Travel.processRequest(req){
   //... then
   processHotel(req, Hotel.makeCall);
}

Travel.processHotel(.., callback){
   //...
   callback(null, Hotel.fillDB); // 1  calls MakeCall
}

Hotel.makeCall(err, callback){
   //...
   callback(); // 2
}

Hotel.fillDB(){

   //...
   return;
}
```

**My problem with this code flow is** (apart from the fact that it's a torture to follow),

1. I donT want to decide from within `Travel`, what `Hotel` should do with its data
2. `Hotel.makeCall`doesn't even know what its callback is!   `//see 1 & 2 in code`

While in other cases this code design might fit well, i think we need an improvement here.

Is it the organization of modules? naming? the call chain?

**PS: in a world without async! how was life? :)**

Comment: Could you provide some more code context? Where are `Travel` and `Hotel` methods called from? How does it look like?

Comment: it s a chain of methods really. we get a request and then sequentially call functions to populate the db..

Comment: but i can put down where they re called from maybe.

Comment: Have you considered promises? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: Did you check out `node-async` library? https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to specify! yes i ve read about both async and promisses. i wanted to learn the best practices without them.